# Print CSS Aligning Tables

Tags: html, css

I am trying to configure my `Print.css` page so that when the user wants to print the selected page it prints in the format that I want.

So on my `Index.cshtml` page I have a table that is using `col-md-1` `col-md-offset-1` and then my second table is from a Partial view but is using `col-md-3` `col-md-offset-3` and on the webpage they are displaying perfectly like this:

```
| Table 1 |        | Table 2 |
| ------- |        | ------- |
| ------- |        | ------- |
| ------- |        | ------- |
```

But when I check my print preview it looks like this:

```
| Table 1 |
| ------- |
| ------- |
| ------- |

      | Table 2 |
      | ------- |
      | ------- |
      | ------- |
```

Now I have my partial view in a `<div></div>` tag and I have actually tried to give that `div`(table 2) and the actual Table (table 1) a `class` that will only affect the Print.css and I gave them the `display:inline-table` property but that did not work. still same result

Here is my HTML:

```
<link href="~/Content/Print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

<table class="table table-striped col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 print-col">
    <caption>Total Sports &amp; Colors</caption>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Total Sports:")
        </th>

        <td>
            @ViewBag.totalSports
        </td>

        <td>
            <text class="percentages">
                @ViewBag.totalSportsPercentage
            </text>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Total Colors:")
        </th>

        <td>
            @ViewBag.totalColors
        </td>

        <td>
            <text class="percentages">
                @ViewBag.totalColorsPercentage
            </text>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="print-col">
    @Html.Action("Test", "TotalTest")
</div>
```

Here is my Print.CSS for the `print-col` class name:

```
.print-col{
    display: inline-table;
}
```

So my question is, how do I get my tables to align like in my webpage for my print.css?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "viewport" of a printed document is smaller than the viewport of `col-md-*` in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get what I was looking for. I gave the first table a `class` and gave it the properties `float: right;` and then I gave the second table a `class` and gave it the properties `float: left;` and in the print preview it displayed the way I wanted.